# Bringing data from Multiple tabel using Left outer Join

Tags: sql, join

I have 4 tables , A,B,C,D.

A stores my Customer Id , B ,C D stores various details of customer.
For Eg.  B stores Education ,C stores Occupation , D stores Interests.

Now a Customer may have not have entry in C ,D or It may have entry in B and D but not in C.

I want to select all the information by joing all the four tables. Customer_id is present in all the four tables. Inner join will clearly not work.

I am thinking of Left outer join. Could someone help me with the requirement.

Comment: `Left outer join` seems like the correct choice; you (left outer) join on `Customer_id` and in the rows where no matching data could be found values from that table will be `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

An LEFT OUTER JOIN will only get the rows where column A:B match or B:C match, if u want to keep the values of certain rows from table C, D in blank u can first make an 
LEFT OUTER JOIN WITH A and B and then make a full outer join with C and D, in that way u are going to be able to keep all the data from C and D no mather if the have or not values in it

I am thinking in somethin like this:

```
 SELECT a.store, b.education, d.storeinterest FROM 

 (
 SELECT * FROM A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN B
 ON A = B
 ) A

 FULL OUTER JOIN  C
  ON  A = C 

 FULL OUTER JOIN D
  ON A= D
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should get you started:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b on
a.customer_id = b.customer_id LEFT OUTER JOIN  c
on a.customer_id  = c.customer_id LEFT OUTER JOIN d
on a.customer_id = d.customer_id
```